# dnssec-keygen -n owner significance

Tags: dns, dnssec

I'm trying to set up ddns (dynamic dns) using keys generated with dnssec-keygen.  I used -n USER "username", thinking this would limit use of the key to "username".  However, anyone who has the key can do ddns updates, which is not what I want.

I'd like to understand the significance of the USER owner type in dnssec-keygen.

Answer (score 0):

The user nametype is for specifying a certificate for authorising the certificates used for Transport Layer Security (TLS) used with email. The idea is that busy email servers can't afford the extra processing it would take to track down and authenticate a TLS certificate via its Certificate Authority. By writing a DNSSEC record the mail servers only need to make a single DNS lookup to validate the connection.

According to the [BIND9 Programmer's Manual](http://www.boran.com/security/sp/bind/man/dnssec-keygen.txt)

> The -n option specifies how the generated key will be used.  nametype can be either ZONE, HOST, ENTITY, or USER to indicate that the key will be used for signing a zone, host, entity or user respectively.
>
> The -p option sets the protocol value for the generated key to protocol-value. The default is 2 (email) for keys of type USER and 3 (DNSSEC) for all other key types.

For reasons it doesn't make entirely clear they decided to group email and other uses under the name USER.

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-based_Authentication_of_Named_Entities) page for DANE is a good start.

The rather pithily titled [SMTP Security via Opportunistic DNS-Based Authentication of Named Entities (DANE) Transport Layer Security (TLS)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7672) RFC 7672 Is every bit as difficult to make sense of as its name suggests! but it does have some useful in depth concepts and explains the basic issues quite well in the introduction.

Unfortunately DNS Doesn't have the sort of granularity that you are looking for. If you have given somebody a key to update then they get to update, DNS doesn't have a process to restrict by anything more complex.

Comment: Michael, that's wonderful!  I wasn't able to find that sort of information with a simple google search.  Thank you so much.